Why do documents with inequalities often display incorrectly?
I am a Maths teacher and regularly download worksheets that after unzipping and opening in Word or as a PDF will have inequalities replaced with ... or ,,, and it is always the same, so ... means less than (I think) and ,,, means greater than. I was wondering why this happens and if there was anything I could do to avoid this as it is a real pain to work out and then I always seem to forget (or not trust myself) when it comes around again.
At present I just have to search through the document to find an example where only one inequality works and then extrapolate from there, which can be incredibly time consuming and often still leaves room for error.

What is the actual file format here? This may be an encoding issue. What language are the documents written in and does it correspond with your language settings

Are there any publicly available examples?

Every Pearson Mark Scheme for Maths seems to have this issue. They are either .doc or .docx and are written in English U.K. and opened in Word using the same language

I looked for .docx from that Pearson source but all the materials available to me ("joe public") on their site seemed to be .pdf. Perhaps you can access other things.
I found a .docx with a simple inequality (just LT, not LTE) but that displayed OK
When I tried opening the PDFs in Word,there are much worse display problems, so assume you are not using that approach. But although LT signs appeared OK, LTE signs did not. They are replaced by a Unicode U+F084 sign (Unicode “Private use area”)...

...
Tried inspecting using a couple of PDF utilities but  couldn’t get to the bottom of the problem. That did reveal that Adobe InDesign is used to produce the PDFs. I suppose it’s possible that someone has used the old Symbol font to insert the LTE sign (symbol decimal 163, hex A3) or some such, and that whatever is used to generate .docx output inserts a sequence like ,,, or ...
